# useEffect wait for another useEffect before triggering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 different useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setElements(undefined);
    };
  }, [elementParam]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentlyFetchedElements) {
      setElements(previouslyFetchedElements => ({ ...previouslyFetchedElements, ...currentlyFetchedElements }));
    }
  }, [currentlyFetchedElements]);
```

- The idea of the 1st `useEffect` is to "restart" the `elements` state, whenever `elementParam` updates.
- When `elementParam` updates, it also triggers and API call that updates `currentlyFetchedElements`
- I don't want to `setElements(undefined)` always, just if `elementParam` it's updated, bc i'm using `elements` to accumulate the API responses(that's why i have 2 different `useEffects`)

**The problem:**
If I mess with `elementParam` long enough, there's a point where the `currentlyFetchedElements` API call is cached, and the 2nd use effect takes place before the 1st one, and i see `elements` as `undefined` when they're not.

How can i fix this?

The only work around i've found so far is adding a `setTimeout` to the 2nd `useEffect` to make sure it takes place after the 1st one but i know there should be a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to keep track of the params you are accumulating for.

Does this work for you?

```js
// assuming elements is a list - however you can adapt it to use an object
const [elements, setElements] = useState([])
const [params, setParams] = useState({})

// keep track of the last params, without causing a re-render 
const lastParams = useRef(params)

useEffect(() => {
  const shouldAccumulate = lastParams.current === params

  if (shouldAccumulate) {
    setElements(elements => [ ...elements, ...newElements ]);
  } else {
    lastParams.current = params
    setElements([]); // or `undefined`
  }
}, [params, newElements]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one `useEffect` instead!

Check the following code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setElements(undefined);

  if (currentlyFetchedElements) {
    setElements(previouslyFetchedElements => ({
      ...previouslyFetchedElements,
      ...currentlyFetchedElements
    }));
  }
}, [elementParam, currentlyFetchedElements]);
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to `setElements(undefined);` always, just if `elementParam` it's updated, bc i'm using `elements` to accumluate the API responses

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the **useState** hook as a boolean value and whenever the one useEffect that u want to trigger first is triggered , change the value to True and then change it to false again in the second useEffect (if u only want it to trigger once):

```
const [isBoolean, setBoolean] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setBoolean(true)
      setElements(undefined);
    };
  }, [elementParam]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentlyFetchedElements && isBoolean) {
      setBoolean(false)
      setElements(previouslyFetchedElements => ({ ...previouslyFetchedElements, ...currentlyFetchedElements }));
    }
  }, [currentlyFetchedElements]);
```

Comment: If I do that, the `elements` will not be updated unless `elementParam` is updated and I need it updated any time `currentlyFetchedElements` changes (since i'm accumulating information there)

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand what u are trying to achieve, but if u want the first useEffect to be triggered even when currentlyFetchedElements is updated, u can add it to the array at the end. 
const [isBoolean, setBoolean] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setBoolean(true)
      setElements(undefined);
    };
  }, [elementParam, currentlyFetchedElements]);

Comment: if i do that, `elements` will get `undefined` anytime `currentlyFetchedElements` is updated... but actually want i want is to accumulate this and all the olds `currentlyFetchedElements` results into `elements` ... UNLESS `elementParam` is updated, on that case, i want to start from scratch